# how to control the flow of data using when properly in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can someone explain to me why this code blocks print those lines 
usually, we use **when** to control the flow of data using multiple possibilities like **is !is in !in** here is my code :

```
fun isNumber(obj: Any) {

    when (obj) {
        !is Long, Int, Float, Double -> {
            println("No it's not a number")
        }
        else -> {
            println("Yes it's a number")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    isNumber(19.10)
    isNumber(19L)
    isNumber(19)
    isNumber(19.10F)

}
```

The Result :

```
No it's not a number
Yes it's a number
No it's not a number
No it's not a number
```

Comment: By the way, the check can also be done as `fun isNumber(obj: Any) = obj is Number`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma-separated conditions are evaluated with `OR`, each by their own, so we should turn this around like this:

```
    when (obj) {
        is Long, is Int, is Float, is Double -> {
            println("Yes it's a number")
        }
        else -> {
            println("No it's not a number")
        }
    }
```

The reason your construct does not work is, when you're leaving out the `is` in `!is Long, Int, Float, Double ->` then we have (simplified):

```
   when (obj) {
            Int -> {
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
```

which means you check if `obj` equals the class `Int`, as opposed to checking if `obj` is an instance of `Int`.

Furthermore, even when we add the `!is` to every number type like:

```
   when (obj) {
        !is Long, !is Int, !is Float, !is Double -> {
            println("No it's not a number")
        }
        else -> {
            println("Yes it's a number")
        }
    }
```

it still won't work because, as mentioned, the conditions will be evaluated with `OR`, so everything will be 'not a number', because everything is either **not** a Long **or** **not** an Int etc.

Comment: This is what I thought, the OP syntax is wrong because he is comparing if `obj` is `Long` but also if `obj` is the class type `Int`, `Float` or `Double`. Said this, your solution neither works but it should.....

Comment: Just a remark: the `Int` appearing in `is Long, Int` is not the type but is the companion object of type `Int`.